# Add a table with borders to email

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I've been using an email macro and one way to add body of the email is HTMLbody.

I want to add a table to the body of email.

```
<table style="width:100%" border = 5px>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Once I send, I get email without table borders.

Comment: Have you tried removing the extraneous whitespace, i.e. `border=5px`? And/or specifying the border styling in the inline style?

Comment: No..that didn't work either.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16033521/1188513) (if not dupe)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an important style sheet to the `TD` elements like this (before the code)

```
<style> td {border:2px black solid !important} </style>
```

if you want the border just around the entire `TABLE` then use this instead

```
<style> table {border:2px black solid !important} </style>
```